# Update and join query

Tags: mysql

I had a table named **stores** whose column named **id** which had some values are to be updated by user_id values from **user** table.

```
update stores s
join users u on u.user_id = s.id
set s.id = u.user_id
where s.id = 100;
```

but the above query does no change to the column values of **s.id**.

Comment: You're trying to change a column to a value to which it must, by definition, already be equal.

Comment: the verbal equivalent of your query : "change column id in table stores to match user_id *where user_id is already equal to id and both are already equal to 100*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid `ON` condition since you are limiting the result to 1 `id`, forthermore if you tell the database to look for id same as id in the other table you couldn't expect it to change. Also you are selecting id from the same table where you want to perform the update so I think you meant to select from table `users`

```
update stores s
join users u 
set s.id = u.user_id
where u.user_id = 100;
```